# Reading Information From a Dynamic Website

Tags: java, web

I have been reading up on this since morning, and I can't find a whole lot information regarding my question.

So, I want to make a java application that reads information (Strings) from a website every time the website updates. Is it possible to do this using Java?

Can I use Scanner? I have seen some recommend using Jsoup, but I haven't found any tutorials. Actually, most of my searches results in SO posts that have not been very useful.

So, can anybody give a "tutorial-like" answer for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, what your browser shows you when you access a website (dynamic or not) is the markup received from the webserver, which is parsed and rendered by the browser to display the website.

To receive that markup, your browser makes one (or multiple) HTTP requests to the webserver.
When you type the URL `www.stackoverflow.com` into your browsers address bar, you browser generates an HTTP request to the server. The response is the site's markup.

So, whether the site's content is dynamic or not, is irrelevant at that point, because the request to a URL (at a given time) will result in the same markup whether that request was sent from the browser or your programm.

So, what you need to do is:

1. make your programm request the sites markup
2. parse the markup
3. Do, what needs to be done with it

There are various frameworks and APIs for that job. One is, as you have mentioned, jSoup.
Check [this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) out for a tutorial.

Some websites also allow passing parameters in the URL like `www.somesite.com?foo=bar`, which is called GET-request. There are also POST-requests and others, but you would need to read on about this yourself.

Hope this helps.